# IDEA Update Project creates merge commit when fast-forward merge is possible

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I just noticed that IDEA's Update Project action with update method Merge creates a merge commit even though a fast-forward merge is possible and git pull would not create a merge commit.

Can I force Update Project to fast-forward merge or do I have to choose the Rebase update method instead?

Comment: I don't understand. Your question addresses local work? The push process? The pull process? The merge process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a request for fast-forward merge during Update project:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-159588

Update project always executes **fetch+merge/rebase,** so it's not a pull operation that creates a merge commit.

As a workaround, you could use **Pull** instead of the **Update project**, or configure merge.ff=only and call merge with –no-ff option when you need a merge commit.